# Apache2 doesn't read .htaccess on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

I need help. I try to create my local test server. I've installed *LAMP* and *DataLife Engine 11.1*. It works, but if i want to go, for example, at `localhost/rules.html` it returns me `404` (because it doesn't exist, obviously), although it should use .htaccess and redirect me to `localhost/index.php?do=rules`

I've already tried a ton of different solutions from the web (such as editing config and enabling rewrite mod). And it still happens. Any suggestions?

P.S. Here's [my configuration file](http://foxgame-studio.000webhostapp.com/apache2.conf) .

Comment: It would be better to include the relevant parts of the config file in the question or use paste.ubuntu.com if needed.

Comment: Please don't post images with texts, copy and paste it! Lets see your `.htacess`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you should edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` in this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

- Where [`AllowOverride All`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is the directive that will allow the override by `.htaccess` file.

Then enable it, if it isn't and restart Apache (or reload its configuration):

```
sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Comment: Dude, you've saved me hours!